# Timer useEffect conditional

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, countdown

My component use conditional render.
Now, i get data from API every 5 second is always.
I need get data from API only when  component is render.
If timer is work, request to API must be stopped.
But request get started if timer stop work and component render Block-component.

My code

```
function Queue() {

    const calculateTimeLeft = () => {

        const stamp = blockData.stamp;
        const getDate = new Date(stamp);
        let minutes = getDate.getMinutes();
        getDate.setMinutes(minutes + blockData.duration);

        const difference = +new Date(getDate) - +new Date();
        let timeLeft = {};
        if (difference > 0) {
            timeLeft = {
                days: Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
                hours: Math.floor((difference / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
                minutes: Math.floor((difference / 1000 / 60) % 60),
                seconds: Math.floor((difference / 1000) % 60)
            };

        }
        return timeLeft;

    };

    const [blockData, getBlockDate] = useState([]);
    const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(calculateTimeLeft());

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            setTimeLeft(calculateTimeLeft());
        }, 1000);

        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        function getBlock() {
            axios.get(URLs.baseUrl + URLs.block, { headers: authHeader() })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                    getBlockDate(res.data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })
        }
        getBlock();
        const interval = setInterval(() => getBlock(), 5000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

    }, []);


    const timerComponents = [];

    Object.keys(timeLeft).forEach((interval, index) => {
        if (!timeLeft[interval]) {
            return;
        }
        timerComponents.push(
            <span key={index}>{timeLeft[interval]} {" "}</span>
        );
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
       
                <div className="form__block">
                    {timerComponents.length ? timerComponents : <Block/>}
                </div>

            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```